# No sound if video is more then 12 seconds

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-capture

I create a custom vido recording app, using AVFoundation.
problem is when recording reaches 13 seconds length the sound disappears from result video entirely. 
I set up camera with is code:

```
private func configure(_ mode: CameraMode) {
    guard let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as? [AVCaptureDevice] else {return}
    for device in devices {
        if device.position == .back {
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if session.canAddInput(input) {
                    session.addInput(input)
                }
                configureVideoOutput(for: device)
                session.startRunning()
            } catch (let error) {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

}


private func configureVideoOutput(for device: AVCaptureDevice) {
    if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) && session.canAddOutput(sessionVideoOutput) {
        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        guard let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) as? [AVCaptureDevice] else {return}
        for device in devices {
            do {
                currentDevice = device
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if session.canAddInput(input) {
                    session.addInput(input)
                    break
                }
            } catch (let error) {
                print(error)
                session.commitConfiguration()
            }
        }
        session.addOutput(sessionVideoOutput)
        session.commitConfiguration()
    }
}
```

and star recording video with this code:

```
 @objc private func takeVideo(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        print("begin take video")
        configure(.video)
        if let _ = sessionVideoOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) {
            let fileName = "mysavefile.mp4";
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            sessionVideoOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
            setCaptureButtonToVideoMode(on: true)
        }
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        print("end take video")
        sessionVideoOutput.stopRecording()
        setCaptureButtonToVideoMode(on: false)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

at the end i save video to camera roll:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    print("capture did finish")
    print(captureOutput)
    print(outputFileURL)
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputFileURL)
    }) { saved, error in
    }
}
```

if video is smaller then 13 seconds everything works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When i am recording a movie I use `VCaptureMovieFileOutput()` as session output and it has property called `movieFragmentInterval` that is set to 10 seconds by default. Changing this property to `kCMTimeInvalid` fixed the problem.

Comment: thanks bro you save my day.

Comment: thanks a lot, bro I am facing this issue for more than a week.

Comment: private lazy var movieFileOutput: AVCaptureMovieFileOutput = {
        let output = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        output.movieFragmentInterval = .invalid
        return output
    }()